# threshold replica lag for secondaryPrefered mongod

Tags: replication, mongodb

Example:
3 node on RS with mongos and mongoc(cluster)

On one Secondary node(on RS) we have replica lag, e.g. - 1h.
So, if my read preference is - `secondaryPrefered` and if I read data from RS, can it happen that I will read data from a node that has a replication lag?
Or does mongodb have some sort of protection mechanisms?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the data you read from SECONDARY might not be up-to-date. The obvious solution if you are no fine with it: read from the PRIMARY.

However, one hour sounds a lot. Did you configure a [Delayed Member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/) or did you configure [storage.oplogMinRetentionHours](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.oplogMinRetentionHours)?

Comment: "Yes, the data you read from SECONDARY might not be up-to-date. The obvious solution if you are no fine with it: read from the PRIMARY."
Thanks, that's all I wanted to hear.